# Vertical align seems not in-effect

Tags: html, css

There are couple of 's in a table whose data length varies from little to very lengthy. I have added overflow scrollbar to my needs. And I am able to left align  contents but for some reason I am unable to vertically center align them.

Please help how I could achieve vertical center alignment, plus retain the overflow scroll. Thanks in advance.

Below is sample table data as I cannot use my whole lenghty table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Table TD with Overflow</title>
    <style>
        table tr td {
            font-family: Courier, "Courier New", Georgia, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            width: 25%; 
        }
        div {
              background-color: lightblue;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100px;
              overflow: auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>
            aa<br>  aaaa<br></div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>
            a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br></div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try examining the methods on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment. There are different ways to accomplish this, both old and new and ever-evolving with CSS advancements.

Answer (score 0):

You can take use of flexbox inside your `div` .
I have added below property to `div` tag css

```
{             display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
}
```

```css
table tr td {
            font-family: Courier, "Courier New", Georgia, sans-serif;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            width: 25%; 
        }
        div {
              background-color: lightblue;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100px;
              overflow: auto;
              text-align: center;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: start;
              align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>
            aa<br>  aaaa<br></div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div>
            a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br></div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                a<br>  aa<br>  aaa<br>  aaaa<br>  aaaaa<br>  aaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaa<br>  aaaaaaaaa<br>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: horizontal left align isn't working in that, what need to modify to make horizontal left aligh and vertical center align please? @devd

Comment: change >>> justify-content: center; to <<<  justify-content: start;

Answer (score 0):

To ****retain** Scrollbar and justify the content to the center** of the cell, you need to add the following code to the `div`  CSS. The use of **Flex** will ensure your div tag centers the content in a vertical direction.

```
div {
              background-color: lightblue;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100px;
              overflow: auto;
              text-align: center;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
        }
```

Here is the codepen link :[Demo Link](https://codepen.io/hardiky/pen/MWeeYYq)

Comment: horizontal left align isn't working in that, what need to modify to make horizontal left aligh and vertical center align please? @HardikYewale

Comment: @Shashi123 please refer the codepen link now , i have done some changes

Comment: sorry i guess i wasn't clear enough and maybe i might have misguided, let me put this way:

lets pick row 1 as an example:    
In row1 the text in col1 have to be aligned like the way the text in col2 and col3 are aligned hortizontally and vertically. The other addition i would need in col1 is to to retain the overflow scrollbar.   
  
In your code, it does gets aligned but seems to have some margin on its left. Please assist modifying it further.

Comment: So you want the text to be sticking to the left?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223235/discussion-between-shashi123-and-hardik-yewale).